# 3rd level menu pop out being chopped short. CSS query

Tags: css

I'm modifyng a joomla menu to have a horizontal pop out for 3rd level menu items but am struggling getting this to display correctly. I've tried here there and everywhere but can't trace the issue.

The menu in question is at http://bit.ly/13ruR7B

And in particular under Support>Downloads (the rest of the menu is fine)
The resulting 3rd level menu items 'Brochures/catalogues' and 'Pricelists are being chopped off, I've hunted around in Firebug but can't find the cause.

Any suggestions gratefully accepted :-)

C

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some overflow:hidden declarations you should remove, then just arrange the third level as you wish.

overflow:hidden is added by javascript on div.dropdown.columns1 and the div beneath it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. pointed me in the right direction. Javascript was the cause.